# Get value, which more times repeated in column

Tags: mysql

Given table `menu`, in him is column  `continent`, for example in him is this datas

```
continent
----------
africa
africa
europe
europe
europe
```

I want get continent name, which is more times in column, that is result must be `europe`.

I write query, but I think my query is difficult and must be exist more ease solution for cases like this. are some ideas?

this my query

```
    SELECT continent FROM (
        SELECT continent, COUNT(continent) AS cnt FROM menu GROUP BY continent
    ) AS t
    WHERE cnt = (
        SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM ( 
            SELECT  COUNT(continent) AS cnt FROM menu GROUP BY continent
        ) AS t2
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT continent FROM (
    SELECT continent, COUNT(continent) AS cnt
    FROM menu
    GROUP BY continent
) AS t
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

I think you can also do it in a single query:

```
SELECT continent, COUNT(continent) AS cnt
FROM menu
GROUP BY continent
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Regards

---

UPDATE:

```
SELECT continent
FROM menu
GROUP BY continent
HAVING count(continent) = 
(
    SELECT COUNT(continent) AS cnt
    FROM menu
    GROUP BY continent
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
    LIMIT 0, 1
)
```

The internal query returns the highest number of repeated items; the value is then used in the external query applied to the HAVING operator to return only items that are repeated exactly that number of time. This works in mysql, I'm not sure with other SQL dialects.

Comment: The second query is correct;  The first query is silly -- I would remove it as a suggestion.

Comment: @Andrea  Thanks, but in this case we not obtain correct results, if in column are 2 (or more) differnt value as maximum times repeated, for example in column are also 3 times continent `azia`

Comment: Let me understand: in case of 2 x africa, 3 x europe, 3 x asia ... you want to get both europe and asia ?